# get the absolute path from a relative path in Tcl

Tags: file, tcl, filepath

Say I have a file, named `./ko`
I want it's full path, which can be (for example) `/foo/bar/ko`
In Perl, one just does

```
File::Spec->rel2abs("./ko")
```

In Ruby, it is:

```
File.expand_path("./ko")
```

How is that done in Tcl?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`file normalize`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M25):

```
file normalize ./ko
```